# How to run a sql statements sequentially?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am running a set of SQL statements sequentially in the AWS Redshift **Query editor**.

```
sql-1
sql-2
sql-3
....
sql-N
```

However, in the Redshift **Query editor**, I cannot run multiple SQL statements. So currently I am running SQL statements one by one manually.

What is the alternative approach for me? For me looks like, I can use the DBeaver.

Is there more programmatic approach i.e. just by using a simple bash script?

Comment: Can you provide some more clarity on what you mean by "AWS Redshift editor" and "Redshift UI"?  I'd guess one of these is the web browser based "Query Editor" that is linked to the Redshift console page.

Comment: @BillWeiner updated the questions

Comment: This totally depends on the tool you are using. A database server itself has not UI such as a "query editor".

Comment: I would like to how I can automate this using a bash script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Linux instance that can access the cluster you can use the `psql` command line tool. For example:

```sh
yum install postgresql
psql -h my-cluster.cjmul6ivnpa4.us-east-2.redshift.amazonaws.com \
     -p 5439 \
     -d my_db \
     -f my_sql_script.sql
```

We recently announced a way to schedule queries: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/amazon-redshift-supports-scheduling-sql-queries-by-integrating-with-amazon-eventbridge/ And even more recently published this blog post that walks you through all the steps using the Console or the CLI: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/scheduling-sql-queries-on-your-amazon-redshift-data-warehouse/ Hope these links help.